# Got error message from Deleting Vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to delete one of the Taxonomy's Vocabulary on Drupal 7.26. It would not allow me to delete and turn out an error message. How can I fix this and be able to delete Vocabulary?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function drpual_static_reset() in
>   /sites/all/modules/metatag/metatag.module on line 271

Comment: For now, I will just delete them from Database table "taxonomy_vocabulary"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this post https://drupal.org/node/1719600 as it explains that the function has a typo. I would recommend updating to the latest version of the metatag module.